# Read an XML Data from TCP Port Socket

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, sockets, tcp

I have a device which send me data over a particular port. The data is in XML Format.

Now I already did a small console application which listen for the data and print out the data on the screen.

Now my plans are to deserialize the xml data or I will create the insert statement into the database.

1) The device send me the data every second (if there is data to send me). 
2) I cannot say how much data the device is going to send me.

How can I make sure to capture all data without loose any information..

Ready to discuss?

CODE in C# or VB.NET

Comment: TCP was designed for the express reason to prevent data loss.  You'll need to explain why you think it won't do the job for you.  One second is roughly 2 billion CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Per XML document, you will need to read continously from the socket stream until you find a matching root end element;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><rootElement> ... </rootElement>
```

Done, and wait for the next document.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant points out, TCP is designed for accurate delivery. To receive all tcp data sent during a connection (which sounds like your case), use the code in my answer at [C# performance methods of receiving data from a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582947/c-performance-methods-of-receiving-data-from-a-socket/5504052#5504052).

Once you've received all of the bytes, you can do the typical conversion to text, e.g. `string stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);`